# What is the purpose of returning an IO object in C++?

Tags: c++, input, io, output

I am attempting to teach myself C++ by reading through a textbook and doing practice problems and stuff, and the topic I am currently learning is a little confusing to me and I am hoping to get some clarification. I have looked online for a clear answer to my question, but have not yet found anything.

I am currently learning the details of IO Classes in the standard library, and the section I am on right now gives some examples that has functions that pass and return IO objects.

For example:

```
istream &get_value(istream &input)
{
    int value;
    input >> value;

    return input;
}

int main()
{
    get_value(cin);
    return 0;
}
```

I understand on a high-level view what is happening here. The `get_value` function has a reference to an input object type and it also takes in a reference to an input object, which in my example I used to commonly used `cin` object. I get that this function is reading input from the user in the console and is storing that input as `value`.

What I do not understand is what the reason for returning the input object is. **Why shouldn't this function have a type `void`?** What could the input object I am using be used for? I know I am not using it for anything right now, but what could it be used for?

Comment: You can also do `cin >> get_value;` which will do the same thing because there's an overload of `>>` that takes a function pointer with the signature `istream&(*)(istream&)` to allow this syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value is so you can "chain" the calls between the stream operators `<<` and `>>`. Operator overloading is a good motivation for this "chaining".

```
using namespace std;
class book {
    string title;
    string author;
public:
    book(string t, string a) : title(t), author(a) { }
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const book &x);
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const book &x)
{
    os << x.title << " by " << x.author << "\n";
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    book b1 { "Around the World in 80 Days", "Jules Verne" };
    book b2 { "The C Programming Language", "Dennis Ritchie" };

    cout << b1 << b2; // chaining of operator<<
}
```

If operator<< didn't return an ostream, we would not be able to pass the modified ostream from the first operator<< to the second one. Instead we would have to write

```
cout << b1;
cout << b2;
```

The same applies for input operations, like in your case, with `>>`

Comment: Is this the main/sole purpose of doing something like this? So we can chain things together to reduce amount of code needed?

Answer (score 1):

To use it again to store another var stored in the buffer. Like `get_value(get_value(cin,v1),v2);`

```
#include<iostream>

std::istream &get_value(std::istream &input,int& value)
{
    input >> value;
    return input;
}

int main()
{

    int v1{}, v2 {};
    std::cout<<"Enter two succesive integers: ";
    get_value(get_value(std::cin,v1),v2);
    std::cout<<"\nThe two input integers are "<<v1<<" and "<<v2;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use it to get another input value; for example:

```
input >> value >> value2;
```

Comment: Or rather `get_value(get_value(input))` in this case. In reality `get_value` would also take a ref param to store result.